# Angularjs and Meteor "Session" reactivity, is there a way?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm trying to work with Meteor and Angularjs. I'm using [Meteor_angularjs](https://github.com/lvbreda/Meteor_angularjs) package, which works OK with `Collections`.

Now I'm trying to use `Session` and my reactive data store:

```
TestCtrl = [
    "$scope",
    function($scope){
        $scope.value = Session.get('someValue');
    }
]
```

This does not work.

**QUESTION:** Any suggestions on how to tie down Meteor's `Session` and Angular?

As far as I understand, I can write directive that will be polling `Session` every so ofter, however I don't think that's a good choice.
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I've tried the following:

```
TestCtrl = [
    "$scope",
    function($scope){
        Meteor.autorun(function(){
            $scope.config = Session.get('testsConfig');
            if (!$scope.$$phase){
                $scope.$digest();
            }
        });
    }
]
```

and it sort of works, however I get the following error:

```
Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11
Error: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:41)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30)
    at derez (http://localhost:3000/test:95:30) angular.js:5526
$get angular.js:5526
$get angular.js:4660
$get.Scope.$digest angular.js:7674
(anonymous function) controllers.js:46
Meteor.autorun.rerun deps-utils.js:78
_.extend.run deps.js:19
Meteor.autorun.rerun deps-utils.js:78
_.extend.flush deps.js:63
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:79
_.extend.flush deps.js:61
_.each._.forEach underscore.js:79
_.extend.flush deps.js:60
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I've tried the service like this (might be wrong usage), still nothing. Now it doesn't update at all on Session value's changes.

```
Meteor.autorun(function(){
    app.factory('ssn', function(){ return{
        get: function(val){
            return Session.get(val);
        }
    }});
});
TestCtrl = [
    "$scope","ssn",
    function($scope, ssn){
        $scope.config = ssn.get('testsConfig');
    }
]
```

**UPDATE 3**: Angular has [`$apply()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) for

> to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries)

At the same time Meteor has [`Meteor.render()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render) for

> Most of the time, though, you won't call these functions directly — you'll just use your favorite templating package, such as Handlebars or Jade. The render and renderList functions are intended for people that are implementing new templating systems.

However, it seems like I just cannot put 2 and 2 together. :(

Comment: What happens if you replace 'if (!$scope.$$phase){
                $scope.$digest();
            }' by $scope.$apply();?

Comment: @asgoth, I get additional error that `Error: $digest already in progress`

Comment: Have you tried to create a service and inject it in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this as an old question with old answers but I see people referring to it so here is the updated answer.

First - there is a [new library](http://www.angular-meteor.com) for angular-meteor that handles those cases for you.

And this library gives you two possible solutions:

1. If you want to bind a Session variable to a scope variable, use the [$meteorSession](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/session) service.
   What it does is that every time the scope variable will change, it will change to Session variable (and trigger an autorun if it's placed inside one). 
   and every time the Session variable will change, the scope variable will change as well (and change the view that it's placed upon).
2. If you are using the Session variable just to get a variable reactive (meaning trigger an autorun), you should use [getReactively](http://angularjs.meteor.com/api/getReactively) .  this just returns the already existing scope variable but trigger an autorun every time it changes.  a good example of this can be found it our [tutorial](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/search-sort-pagination-and-reactive-vars).

   - Note: In anyway, when you use Tracker.autorun inside Angular, you need to connect it to a scope.  this can be easily done if you replace Tracker.autorun with the [$meteorUtils autorun function](http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.0/utils)

Comment: I'll blindly accept your answer, hoping it's correct and pulling it up the stream. I haven't done any meteor stuff for a while now, so cannot verify.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is an option (might not be the best but it works I think)

```
app.service('Session',function($rootScope){
    var self = this;
    self.objects = {};
    self.get = function(name){
            self.objects[name] = {"value" : Session.get(name)};
            Meteor.autorun(function() {
                    var i = Session.get(name);
                    if(self.objects[name].value != i){
                            if (!$rootScope.$$phase){
                                    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
                                            self.objects[name].value = i;
                                    });
                            }
                    }
            });
            return self.objects[name];
        }
        self.set = function(name,value){
            self.objects[name].value  = value;
            Session.set(name,value);
        }
        return self;
});
```

Call it in the $scope like this
    $scope.test = Session.get("test");

In the view as {{test.value}}. Sorry for the late answer .

Happy new year!

Comment: Yes, it does work, thanks. However, when I put `Meteor.subscribe('tests', ssn.get('testsConfig'));
        $scope.Tests = new Meteor.AngularCollection("tests",$scope);
        $scope.tests = $scope.Tests.find({});` into the same controller, I get the same error `Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11`. Any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: I added the minimal repo [at github](https://github.com/alex-okrushko/meteor-angular-binding) maybe you can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
angular.module('yourmod', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var c = Deps.autorun(function (comp) {
     //... put reactive stuf on scope.....
     if(!comp.firstRun) {
       // only do not do aply at first run becaulse then apply is already running.
       $scope.$apply()
     }
  });

  // and to realy make it nice...
  $scope.on('$destroy', function () {c.stop()});
}])
```