# Is $scope in AngularJS equivalent to Session in MeteorJS?

Tags: angularjs, meteor

I am learning AngularJS and MeteorJS and would like to use them both. I noticed that each package has their own object to store global variables: `$scope` in Angular, and `Session` in MeteorJS.

Does it make sense to sync them, i.e., a variable change in $scope will cause corresponding change in Session and vise versa? How should I go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs and Meteor "Session" reactivity, is there a way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14073306/angularjs-and-meteor-session-reactivity-is-there-a-way)

Answer (score 0):

*(Not an entirely satisfying answer but rather a quick heads-up as I'm currently experimenting/evaluating with both right now)*

Meteor uses the Session as a global cache object whereas Angular $scope is simply but powerfully based on the classic concept of scopes -- and along the way brings an intuitive understanding of what it means. In other words, controllers and directives in Angular have their own $scope, while Meteor templates and pretty much all objects could all access the Session object.

As far as I see the current benchmarking game between Angular and Meteor, both are very well thought frameworks but don't fit too well together as many components are redundant -- same observation for Backbone and Meteor. Reactive programming is achieved in Meteor, same as Angular does it with the two-way binding variables. Meteor seems to make things easier by enabling one language and toolbox for both client and server.